# How to do dynamically a Altorouter

Tags: php, altorouter

I used Altorouter in PHP, and I try to dynamic my router. 
I have an architecture specific with folders, sub-folders, sub-sub-folders.

I have try to do this

```
//dynamic routage for root main pages
$router->map( 'GET', '/[:pageName]', 'HomeControler::pageRedirect');

//dynamic routage for subfolder pages
$router->map( 'GET', '/[:folder]/[:pageName]', ' 
HomeControler::subPageRedirect');
```

That's working, but I just matching with folder / page. 
I wont doing this method for all sub-folders. 
How can I detect folders, sub-folders, automatically ?

And In my controller,

I control the folders like that ?

```
// Dynamic mapping to pages
public static function pageRedirect($pageName) {
    self::redirectTo(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../front/$pageName.php");
}
```

And I do condition if he doesn't find in this pages ?

Comment: Are you going to have dynamic folders with files?

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamic folders with files"?

Comment: Will your code  create some dynamic folders with files which you will need to map with the urls at runtime?

Comment: Yes when I will create folders, subfolders or files, I mapping them and write a correctly URL

Comment: If you gonna have fixed number of folders and subfolders then you just don't need to add additional code to map those urls with folder and files , You should statically define those.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi Thx a lot for your answers. I'm a newbie in PHP and I don't understand correctly what you mean. Then you suggest to not replace my code with a dinamycally mapping ?

Comment: Yes if you already know how many folder or sub-folders you gonna have.

Comment: But if a non-programmer wants to create many folders, subfolders and pages tomorrow, that's will not mapping alone right ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
 $router->map('GET', '/[*:target]', 'yourController')
```

This will map any request to your controller. How you interpret `target` in your controller is up to you (looking in folders etc.).